# Python-for-android, no module name tty

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, kivy, buildozer

I'm trying to use the `pty` module on my application. Although, my application crashes and gives the following output on logcat:

```
.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/python2/armeabi-v7a/python2/python-install/lib/python2.7/pty.py", line 11, in <module>
11-22 23:23:35.783  4760  4877 I python  : ImportError: No module named tty
11-22 23:23:35.787  4760  4877 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I assume the pty module was not meant to be run on android?? It cannot access the tty module, which is only accessible from computers. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/481906/what-does-tty-stand-for

Comment: Also if you take a look at the source, it says "Only tested on linux" https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/13006728/

Comment: Thank you @Plays2.

Comment: So, how can I simulate a tty on android using kivy? Can you help me?

Comment: I'm familiar with android and python, but separately. I've never tried using python to write android applications. What specifically do you need to do? I would assume you'd need root access

Comment: I want to make a android terminal using Kivy, is it possible? For now, I can run simple commands on my application, like ping or wget. But, I can't su or nano for example. Su gives a message that it must be run in a terminal

Comment: I think you'd be better off using Java. Is your device rooted?

Comment: Yes, it's rooted. I want to use Kivy for that. Do you have a hint?

Comment: Oops I made it an answer by accident. But yea not a clue

Comment: @Plays2, I created another question more related with my problem. If you want to watch it and see if anyone answer, you can see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40755167/how-to-simulate-a-terminal-in-android-using-kivy

Comment: The tty module is blacklisted by default. I'll probably change this in python-for-android (I don't think it needs to be), but for now you need to whitelist `tty.pyo`.

Comment: Thank you @inclement, it solved my problem!