# How to simulate a terminal in Android using Kivy?

Tags: android, python, terminal, kivy, terminal-emulator

I'm trying to build a Android terminal emulator using Kivy, for now, I can use some simple commands, like `ping` and `wget`, and grab their output using `subprocess.PIPE`, but I can't figure out how to use more complex commands like `su` or `nano`. For instance, `su` gives a error saying that is must be run in a terminal. What I have create a Android terminal emulator using Kivy?

Comment: Check if your app has appropriate permission set for using `su` (yes, there is one)

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr, I checked the su permission and its working now. But nano gives a error message: Error opening terminal: unknown

Comment: So, how to create a terminal emulator for Android using Kivy?